# How to make a sharp edge on a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I'm trying to model a battleaxe and I'm trying to sharpen an edge I created and so far using bevel, extruding and scaling doesn't do anything but mess it up.

[image: screenshot of the mesh]

Is there anyway I'm able to make the end of the mesh converge at a sharp angle?

Comment: When I scale it down it looks like this

https://gyazo.com/4cedad51f7955f7d4ebfee8fe5ec28a2

Comment: First, choose another Pivot Point, e.g. *Median Point*, second, scale with Proprotional Editing enabled (O). It's correctly written in the answer that you have too much edge loops already, although it's possible to scale with them if you really need them.

Answer (score 2):

Woah there! that subdivision you did is what is holding you back at the moment.

You'll want to change the edge flow in order to be able to fix the curvature in the way you said.

It should look more like this:
[image: Properish edge flow]

However, there is a way to give this mesh the shape you want, even in its current state.

Step 1: select all the faces that will be starting the edge.

Step 2: hit E, right click and then Alt+S then drag your mouse until you like how it looks, then left click.

Step 3: select the angular edges that you want to get rid of.

Step 4: hit X and select dissolve edges.

Here is an image explaining the process:

[image: Tutorial]

Comment: Can you please repeat the steps? I don't think that the steps you wrote work because when I extrude it, the top corners start to stretch and it starts to look weird it doesn't stretch like yours in step 2. I also tried to dissolve the edges and it doesn't work.

Comment: Never mind I just decided to restart and do it the correct way. Only took like 10 mins to redo it. Next time I'll make sure to plan it out rather than just start modeling and running into problems later on.

Comment: You have to hit E to extrude and then right click. after that you'll want to hit alt+s

Comment: also there must be an edge running through the middle of the faces (as shown on the image)